# Google Maps API Geocoding doesn't work all the time

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am attempting to turn an address into lat and long coordinates based on google maps geocoding API. I have done a fair amount of testing and it seems that it gets the correct coordinates about half of the time.

Is it common to only work some of the time or is there something I can do to enter the address in differently?

Basically I am just replacing all the spaces with `+`

Any tips or advice would be much appreciated.

link for reference:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was allowing for line breaks as well during the data input. So, in some cases this led to a the url having a space in it which caused the lat and lng coordinates to be incorrect. I just had to replace them with a `+` and it works every time now.